# Java Socket Creation is taking too long

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to execute the following Java code on an Intel Based Linux machine (Custom Minimal Linux version: Linux 2.6.18). Socket creation is taking too long (~ 3mins). When I run the Top command in Linux, Its showing me that my Java process is in Sleep. Can some one tell me whats going on with this?

> Java Version: 1.6.0_24

```
try{
    System.out.println("Creating a Socket at: " + new Date());
    s = new Socket(hostname, p);
    System.out.println("Socket creation complete at: " + new Date());
    s.close();
}
```

> **UPDATE: Tested with Java 1.7 (1.7.0_01) and it works fine. Whole program runs under 5
>   seconds. Socket creation returns almost instantly.**

Comment: How long does `telnet <hostname> <port>` take from the shell prompt (with the same `<hostname>` and `<port>` as your code)?

Comment: Telnet waits for some time and gets a message "Connection Closed by Foreign host".. May be its timing out. I know that server is running. After taking that long to create a socket, my java program really was able to interact with that server well. Only problem is Socket creation time.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is probably the DNS problem. Are you using host name or IP? If you are using name, try to ping it. How long does ping take? I guess it will take a lot of time. Anyway try to use IP address in your java program. I hope it will solve your problem.

If not check your network settings, firewall, NAT etc. Probably start from local connection, i.e. try your program on localhost, then on some other host in your local network, then on host in other network (if you need this).

Good luck.

Comment: I am using IP address. Not the domain name. Ping is very fast because the server I am trying to connect is in the same network (just one hop).

Comment: How long does `telnet IP port` take?

Comment: Telnet waits for some time and gets a message "Connection Closed by Foreign host".. May be its timing out. I know that server is running. After taking that long to create a socket, my java program really was able to interact with that server well. Only problem is Socket creation time.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a whole morning to get around it.

In my ubuntu, I try to turn the ipv6 setting(System Settings->Network) from "Automatic" to "Ignore", then everything is ok.

Seems it is a bug for JDK1.6, and I will try JDK1.7 soon.